# Shutdown JBoss 7 AS along with host-controller

Tags: jboss7.x

I use JBoss 7.1.1-FINAL AS. Its configured to startup in domain mode with default settings. I use the domain.sh file to start up the server which starts 4 java processes:

1. Host-controller
2. Process-controller
3. server-one
4. server-two

In order to shutdown the server, i invoke the following command:

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect controller=host:9999 /host=master:shutdown
```

This brings down the 2 servers, server-one and server-two.

I would like to know how to stop host-controller and process-controller.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command mentioned above is the command to shutdown the server. Apparently, this started working recently. I do not know what the issue was. The host-controller and the process-controller also shutdown with this command.

Answer (score 1):

You can try either command. They both work for me;stopping all processes. #1 is the shorthand command connecting to the controller.

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect /host=master:shutdown
./jboss-cli.sh --connect controller=localhost:9999 /host=master:shutdown
```

Cheers.