# Wildfly and Process controller

Tags: jboss, wildfly, administration

I see here and there the term of **process controller** in Jboss articles, but I can't find any description of it in the official documentation.

- [Search in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/dosearchsite.action?queryString=process%20controller&where=AS71&type=&lastModified=&contributor=&contributorUsername=) : no trace
- old documentation : [some trace](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7UserGuide?_sscc=t)
- [question in Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165363/shutdown-jboss-7-as-along-with-host-controller) : seems important

So the question is : what is it ? Is it an old concept ? If so, what is the replacement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process Controller is a tiny Java process which is in charge to mediate between the Domain controller and the Host controller. You don't have much control over it, as it is spawned when the Host controller is started, except that you can define the local port and address where it's listening to:

```
   --interprocess-hc-address=<address> Address on which the host controller
                                       should listen for communication from
                                       the process controller


   --interprocess-hc-port=<port>       Port on which the host controller
                                       should listen for communication from
                                       the process controller
```